# regex patterns - noob in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have been testing and googling but still could'nt work out pattern to validate comma separated numbers.

9 digits long, numbers only, no spaces, leading number for each digit cannot be zero

Tried

```
^(?:\s*\d{9}\s*(?:,|$))+$
```

but no go

Note that commas are required since the input file should between 3 up to 20 (max) comma separated integers

Comment: Try [`^[1-9]\d{8}(?:,[1-9]\d{8})*$`](https://regex101.com/r/sqUeRt/1) or - if there must be at least 1 comma - [`^[1-9]\d{8}(?:,[1-9]\d{8})+$`](https://regex101.com/r/sqUeRt/2).

Comment: Or do you mean there must be at least 3 comma-separated numbers and up to 20? Then you need `^[1-9]\d{8}(?:,[1-9]\d{8}){2,19}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that there should be no spaces, but you used `\s*` (0+ whitespaces) in your pattern. Also, `(?:,|$)` matches a `,` or end of string, so your pattern allows a trailing `,`.

I suggest using

```
^[1-9]\d{8}(?:,[1-9]\d{8}){2,19}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqUeRt/3)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[1-9]` - the first digit of the 9-digit number cannot be zero, `1` to `9` only
- `\d{8}` -  the 8 remaining digits of the number
- `(?:,[1-9]\d{8}){2,19}` - 2 to 19 (in total, 3 to 20) occurrences of

  - `,` - comma
  - `[1-9]\d{8}){2,19}` - see above
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor this pattern did it and confirmed by regex demo

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match('=^[1-9][0-9,]*$=', $x);` should do it, unless you're saying the number *must* be 9 digits long (with optional commas? or are the commas required?), in which case try something like `preg_match('=^[1-9][0-9]{2},?[0-9]{3},?[0-9]{3}$=', $x);`

Comment: thanks for the reply man. they must be 9 digits long, commas are required since the input file should between 3 up to 20 (max) comma separated integers

Comment: So -- the commas are not part of the number (e.g. 500,000,000)?  In that case, use [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to split the file input on the commas, then use `=^[1-9][0-9]{8}$` to validate.

Comment: thanks for the help alan ^[1-9]\d{8}(?:,[1-9]\d{8}){2,19}$ was the pattern i was looking for